# Re-ordering the x-axis values in Power BI - "Sort By" not working

Tags: sorting, powerbi, dax

I have a chart where the x-axis values are showing as:
0-3 months, 10-12 months, 4-6 months, 7-9 months (see picture below) 
and i want them to be in ascending order. i am sorting by "months open" and have it selected by "Sort Ascending"

[image]

This is the grouping i have for the months and this is what is being sorted:

[image]

Not sure why the "10-12" months group shows between 0-3 and 4-6, and I've searched other forum posts to try their solutions but nothing is working for me. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the sort is treating your month label as simple text.   So:

- 0    (0-3 Months)
- 1    (10-12 Months)
- 4    (4-6 Months)
- 7    (7-9 Months)

Option 1 is pretty straight forward (but kind of a "hack") . Change your labels to two (2) digit months like this, your sort should work:

- 0   (0-03 Months)
- 04  (04-06 Months)
- 07  (07-09 Months)
- 10  (10-12 Months)

Option 2 may be more to your liking though it's a bit more complex ...

1. Using Data Entry, create a new table that has nothing but the month label values in the order you want them to appear.
2. Set up a relationship to the month label in your new table from your month label in the source
3. Base your slicer or other visualizations on the month label from your new table.

Comment: THank you @heavydnickell this helped me figure it out. 
the solution in this linked post is basically what you said but with pictures: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Custom-Sorting-in-PowerBI/td-p/126534

Comment: glad to assist :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ordering in power bi is based on the data in the data source. That means, 
First it will consider special characters (<>+{}-. Etc)
Second numbers(0-9)
Third alphabets (a-z, A-Z).

Comment: How does that answer the question?